# Style MUI React component with theme and ThemeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm learning about MUI components in React, using MUI 5 and React 17. The MUI components are from a 3rd party lib so I don't have direct access to them. I am trying to restyle a component with a new theme passed to a MUI `ThemeProvider`. Browser dev tools shows CSS class and `min-width 36px`.

```
.css-tneosy-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiMenuItem-root .MuiListItemIcon-root
min-width: 36px;
```

I try to override `min-width` using a new theme:

```
const rawMuiTheme = {
    palette: { ... },
    components: {
        MuiButtonBase: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    MuiMenuItem: {
                        styleOverrides: {
                            root: {
                                minWidth: '16px',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        MuiListItemIcon: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    minWidth: '16px',
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

const muiTheme = createTheme(rawMuiTheme);
<MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
```

But `min-width` does not change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played around MUI theme a little and have a not ideal, but working solution, you can check it in the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-cache-9bndd1?file=/index.tsx):

```
   const theme = createTheme({
      components: {
        MuiButtonBase: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              "& .MuiListItemIcon-root": {
                minWidth: "16px !important"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Sometimes MUI ignores theme overrides, so I managed to get this to work only with *!important* flag.
Without *!important* you get this:

[image]